# No GPU detected on AWS SageMaker pytorch-1.8-gpu-py36 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I've got a pytorch-1.8-gpu-py36 instance running on AWS SageMaker Studio.

If I'm in a notebook in and I enter:

```
!nvidia-smi -L
```

I get:

```
GPU 0: Tesla T4 (UUID: GPU-786d298a-2648-3506-6c3a-f541fa46d777)
```

But if I open a terminal and enter:

```
nvidia-smi -L
```

I get command not found, and if I try to run a .py script that requires a GPU I get this error from PyTorch:

```
pytorch_lightning.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: 
You requested GPUs: [0]
But your machine only has: []
```

Do the terminal windows and notebooks run off of separate instances even if they're in the same folder? Is there a way to get the terminal to be part of the same instance as the notebook?

I can't simply run the command line from the notebook as I require a Conda environment that can't be activated from the notebook interface.

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Studio's *System terminals* run on different instances than your notebooks (see [Studio architecture here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks.html)).

To use the terminal for your GPU instance that your notebook runs on, click the 'Image Terminal' icon from your notebook.
You can also use New Launcher -> Image Terminal after selecting PyTorch GPU optimized as your SageMaker image.

[image: SageMakerStudioImageTerminal]